# Adding clickable links to JSON derived list

Tags: json, swift, list, swiftui

I have a JSON file of products and URLs to those product pages that I’ve arranged in a searchable list.  I can’t find a way to implement the urls as clickable into my list items, either as links to open into just straight up safari or as sheets to my web viewer.

I just need any way to make each product link to their respective url, please!

I tried adding the link to each product in the JSON file, but the only way I can get them to show up is as text only. I also use sheets in other parts of the app, and tried adding each link to a case in the switch but I can’t find a way to add the case names to each item in the list.